# Polymer: core-header-panel inside paper-dialog doesn't work

Tags: polymer

The header panel can't be seen inside an paper-dialog (overlay). If I remove the :host {position: relative} from core-header-panel.html, the panel is shown but nothing else can be clicked except the header panel.

```
<paper-dialog opened="true" autoCloseDisabled="true" target="" transition="paper-dialog-transition-bottom">
    <core-header-panel mode="waterfall">
        <core-toolbar>
            <paper-button label="Select" autofocus></paper-button>
            <paper-button label="Save"></paper-button>
        </core-toolbar>
    </core-header-panel>

    //other elements
</paper-dialog>
```

Comment: I just pasted your code in a working application and it showed, no problems. Can you check your .html `<link>`s and post them here?